# Laravel 5.4 : save files with real name

Tags: local-storage, laravel-5.4

I use `Storage::disk('local')->put('myfiles/',$request->file)` to save files on disk . but the `Storage` save file with a hashed name.
if you have a look to the source `put` returns `putFileAs` at the last step :

```
 public function putFile($path, $file, $options = [])
{
    return $this->putFileAs($path, $file, $file->hashName(), $options);
}
```

as you see file name is created by laravel. 
 Is there any way to save files on server with its real file name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests)

## Retrieving The Original Name Of An Uploaded File

```
$name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Try this: `$request->getClientOriginalName();`

## Edit

All together save it like this

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('myfiles/' . $request->getClientOriginalName() . $request->getClientOriginalExtension() ,$request->file)
```

## edit2

Try using the `PutFileAs` method as described in the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)

Comment: thanks but this is not an answer to the question, i need to SAVE file with its real name NOT GET its real name

Comment: @alex ow sorry i assumed you know how you will need to put the filename and extension after the folder check my edited answer

Comment: your solution does not work on laravel 5.4 . as i stated file name is selected by laravel , please take a look at the source code iv'e provided

Comment: Try using the `PutFileAs` method as described in the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Comment: thanks. this the correct answer.  please edit your answer based on your last comment so i can select it as accepted

Comment: I got this error: 

> Request::getClientOriginalName does not exist.

Comment: @realtebo Request->getClientOriginalName  **